# error when checking target expected dense_2 to have shape (13 ) but got array with shape ( 40)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, anaconda, artificial-intelligence

Hello  I  am  writing  a  neuron  for  determining  the  figures  counting

```
def get_image_size():
    img = cv2.imread('gestures/0/100.jpg', 0)
    return img.shape // 50*50

def get_num_of_classes():
    return len(os.listdir('gestures/')) //13classes

image_x, image_y = get_image_size()
```

The  CNN  Model

```
def cnn_model():
    num_of_classes = get_num_of_classes()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5), strides=(5, 5), padding='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    filepath="cnn_model_keras2.h5"
    checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
    #checkpoint2 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint1]
    return model, callbacks_list
```

Trainning

```
def train():
    with open("train_images", "rb") as f:
        train_images = np.array(pickle.load(f))
    with open("train_labels", "rb") as f:
        train_labels = np.array(pickle.load(f), dtype=np.int32)

    with open("test_images", "rb") as f:
        test_images = np.array(pickle.load(f))
    with open("test_labels", "rb") as f:
        test_labels = np.array(pickle.load(f), dtype=np.int32)

    train_images = np.reshape(train_images, (train_images.shape[0], image_x, image_y, 1))
    test_images = np.reshape(test_images, (test_images.shape[0], image_x, image_y, 1))
    train_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
    test_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(test_labels)

    model, callbacks_list = cnn_model()
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), epochs=50, batch_size=100, callbacks=callbacks_list)
    scores = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)
    print("CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

but  i'm  getting  this  error  :  `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (13,) but got array with shape (40,)` and i searched about some solutions but nothing work , if any one have an idea how to solve it please

Comment: Your network is configured to output 13 classes, but it seems that your labels have 40 classes instead. Its up to you to find out why there is a difference, as there is no code here that generates those arrays. This can also be seen by looking at the shapes of train_labels

Comment: I'm trying to crack captchas and even I face the same error. Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the number of labels you have for training is not the same as you are predicting. Looking at the code, it seems like `num_of_classes != train_labels.shape[1]`. If you have just a vector of classes labels such as `[3, 7, 1]` then you can use `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` which will encode the targets when training for you.

Comment: thank u nuric for your answering , i already tried to do this :`loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` but i got this error  `error when checking target expected dense_2 to have shape (1 ) but got array with shape ( 40)`

Comment: what does your `train_labels` look like? There is essentially a shape mismatch between that and the output of the model.